# Using an or statement in a conditional list comprehension to filter columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements

I'm trying to filter my columns in dataframe that contain the letters "R" or "H".

The code works when I only search for 1 of the letters but it's returning all the columns when I add an `or` statement.

I was wondering if it was possible to use the or in a list comprehension. Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data_sorted = data.sort_values('Timestamp', ascending=False)
four_dec_cols = [col for col in data_sorted if 'H' in col]
```

failed code:

```
four_dec_cols = [col for col in data_sorted if 'RB' or 'H' in col]
```

Utlimately, I want to round the columns that contain 'H' or 'R' to 4 decimal places and all the rest to 2 decimal places so if theres maybe a more direct way to do that, i'd appreciate the suggestion.

Thanks so much!

Edit:
So ideally - i'd like to return this dataframe with any column that contins RB or H rounded to 4 decimal places and everything else rounded to 2.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `'R'` or `'RB'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('RB|H')]
```

Comment: this is way better! is there a notcontains or similar to get everything but these two columns?

Comment: There is a negate `~`: `~df.columns.str.contains('RB|H')`

Comment: last question: that returns an index object. whats the most effecient way to apply a 2 decimal round to just those columns

Comment: `df[cols] = df[cols].round(2)`?

Comment: that returns only the columns that contained those letters rounded - none of the other columns are there. it's ok though - that's a separate question - i'll try and figure it out. thanks again!

Comment: You’re welcome. Although, it would really help if you provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code checks whether `'RB'` is true (existent) and hence returns all columns. Try:

```
four_dec_cols = [col for col in data_sorted if 'RB' in col or 'H' in col]
```